# Excel Solver: Solving matrix values to match row/column sum according to reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I've been trying to program Excel Solver to fill the values of a matrix so that the sum of rows and columns match preestablished values. See image:

[Excel Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2nSN.png)

I understand this problem has infinite solutions that's why I want to constraint the problem by having a reference matrix whose weights (percentage of total sum) I want to match. I've tried to accomplish this by summing the differences between the weighted reference matrix and the solution matrix and solving to minimize the absolute value:

> =((SUM(B19:F31))^2)^(1/2)

[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2ycb.png)
[Solver Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzBSh.png)

Unfortunately excel cannot find a feasible solution. Any ideas why?